# Android Emulator apps not connected to network after importing SSL cert

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, ssl-certificate

My emulator runs behind company's VPN so I needed to install the corporate root CA for SSL to work. After doing so I can access https on Chrome but **none of the apps works - network calls are falling with all apps (Android  built-in and third party) ** ...

I am using:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- Palo Alto GlobalProtect
- Pixel 2 Android 9 Pie API 29 (x86-64)
- Network settings: LTE/WIFI enabled, original DHCP and APN settings
- Proxy settings: N/A

Can verify the certificate has been install properly and https is working with chrome:

[image: img]

Any ideas? Let me know if more info is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the root certificate for the network to system trust store - modify the simulator image to install the certificates.

Follow instructions [here](https://medium.com/hackers-secrets/adding-a-certificate-to-android-system-trust-store-ae8ca3519a85) - will need to fall back to API level <=25 or so to support this modification though ...